# Error 403 when accessing an address to rewrite

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /project/clients/index.php?database=$1&module=products [L,QSA]
```

The directory structure is as follows:

```
/var/www/project/clients/index.php
```

When writing the address `"http://host/products/clientA/"` is directed into the `"/project/clients/index.php?database=clientA&module=products"`. In my virtual machine with linux (debian)  in my PC works fine, but the server linux returns a 403 error.

But if I switch to rewrite this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^project/products/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /project/clients/index.php?database=$1&module=products [L,QSA]
```

and then write the url: `"http://host/project/products/clientA/"`, works well

The permissions on `"/var/www/project/"` and sub directories, is right for apache.

thanks.

[initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631580/problems-working-with-rewrite-in-apache2)

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652598/error-403-when-accessing-an-address-to-rewrite:

You should put the .htaccess file in the docroot directory (public_html or htdocs).
Example:
URL: `http://example.com/somedir/somefile.php`
Path: `/var/www/example/htdocs/somedir/somefile.php`
.htaccess should be placed in `/var/www/example/htdocs/.htaccess`.

When you get a HTTP 403 (or 500) error, you should look in your error logs first.